# What is the difference between Analytics of Landing Pages and All Pages in Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, analytics

I am posting two screen shots of my Google Analytics in which Avg. Session Duration is different. Why is that ??

One screenshot is from Landing Page and other is from All Pages tab. I am using a WordPress plugin which shows page by page stats https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-analytify/  and It is showing that page stats from Landing page.

[image]

[image: Landing Page]

Comment: The All Pages report does not have an "Avg. Session Duration" field. The metrics in this report are hit-level. There is an "Avg, Time on Page" field, but this does not refer to the session, but to the time spent on a distinct url. Landing pages are pages that started a session, potentially with many subsequent pageviews, so Average session duration is average of the time spent on all visited urls combined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing two ways of looking at pages:

- the first one (pages) describes how many pages were seen overall. In your case, 69 pageviews for that page and 61 entrances (notice that last number?)
- the second one (landing pages) deceptively reports sessions *starting* on that given page. Because they're session-based, they take bounce rate into account. Remember that high bounce rate = low average session time. So those 61 sessions that started on that given page resulted in 90+% bounce rate.

Try applying a segment to exclude bounce sessions and you should see your average session time get much closer to the 2 minutes listed in the pages report

Comment: I want to accept this answer - but I can't I need 15 points for reputation.

Comment: This anwer is not correct. As I've pointed out there is no session duration field in the pages report (anybody who does not believe me just needs to read the column labels in the posted pictures).

Comment: That's because you're comparing apples and oranges. Time spent on page and Average are two different metrics based on two different scopes.

Comment: Both comments helped me reaching the solution and I want to award you both.

Answer (score 0):

Landing pages will show you how people entered your web site and it is good for acquisition analysis.

All pages report will show you how your pages perform regardless if they entered the site through that page or not. This is why you see additional metrics such as %Exit rate (since bounce rate applies ONLY to landing page) and page value (since you can not run a conversion rate report on all pages).

You can use your ALL pages report in order to see how people navitgate to your site, which pages are important as "secondary level" pages and how they contribute to your conversion path.

You can read more in how to do that here: http://digitalinsightsworld.com/digital-insights/path-analysis-google-analytics-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Site admin misunderstood between these two metrics.

Landing Page - Avg Session Duration -  Continuous Page duration Avg Time

All Page (From Behaviour) - Avg Time on Page - Amount of time spend on single page.

Refer this information, it is clearly explain this link https://www.studentcpu.com/2020/03/google-analytics-important-kpi-monitor.html Please refer it. you will get clear insight.